# Android Studio refuses to install app because of signature

Tags: android-studio, signature

I have Android Studio 4.1.3, and today I updated my phone to Android 11.

I open my Android Studio, an app, and when I try to install the app into the phone with studio it tells me:

```
The device already has an application with the same package but a different signature.
In order to proceed, you will have to uninstall the existing application

WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!

Do you want to uninstall the existing application?
```

My app strongly uses External storage, where my users have tens of GBs of data. They CANNOT uninstall their apps!

Why is this happening, what signature is studio talking about, and how can I fix this?

Could this be a problem with my #HOME/.android folder? I was messing with it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I restored my $HOME/.android folder with an old backup, and everything works as expected. Probably I messed up or removed my original signature file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed app from Playstore it has basically signed with their key. If you have already installed the same app from Playstore and you try to install exact app with same package name and with the release version you will get this..

So solution is simply select `debug version` if you are installing from Android studio or simple just uninstall and reinstall from Android Studio itself.

Also check if you are targeting `API level 30 in build gradel`

Check Out documentation  [Set up the Android 11 SDK](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/setup-sdk) and [Compatibility framework tools](http://developer.android.com/guide/app-compatibility/test-debug)

Comment: No Playstore. This is an app that I made. I can reinstall, but my users cannot since they would lose all their data. How do I select "debug version"? Usually I just click in _"Build > Build bundles > Build apks"_

Comment: your users will install from Playstore? if yes than it would be no problem at all.

Comment: No. My users install the apk I provide.

Comment: then also it should not be a problem.. Just make sure you are targeting API 30 in grade build.

Comment: I need to target 29. I have never had a problem like this before.

Comment: no you need to target API 30 because you said you are installing on Android 11

Comment: I can target older APIs, why not? I have apps that target API 14 and run perfectly on Android 10. Of course I cannot target API 29 and run on Android 5...

Comment: just go to gradle build and change target  29 to 30

Comment: I NEED to target 29 (wifi on/off).

Comment: but for Android 11 you must target API 30... or it will not be installed.

Comment: It should be installed on any Android >= 29. Your claim would imply that you need one build for each Android.

Comment: it should specify min and max target version like this.          `minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 30`

Comment: My _minSdkVersion_ is 14. It should install on any android >= 14. I cannot target 30 because I want to turn wifi on/off. So target = 29.

Comment: yes it says any app >= api 14 but your target 29 says <=29..  and you are using Android 11 which requires API 30.. so plz just change it to 30. its that simple

Comment: You are wrong. target has nothing to do with the max android that allows to be installed. Anyway, just in case, I changed to target 30, and the problem persists. This is NOT the issue. I am almost sure this is a signature problem.

Comment: cool but please refer these two links https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/setup-sdk and  https://developer.android.com/guide/app-compatibility/test-debug

Comment: Thanks for the links. Yes, Google always asks you to target the last SDK version (even studio _lint_ does). But as I wrote I cannot target 30 (and, anyway, this did not fix my problem).

Comment: it will work perectly fine till android 10. you can try on any android 10 or below. It can also work in Android 11 just need simple setting follow 2nd link.